# Angular i18n dependency problems

Tags: angular, internationalization

I'm trying to add i18n to my angular app.  While running the extract and merge process from the angular cli I get the following error:

```
> ng xi18n myapp --i18n-format xlf --output-path src/i18n --i18n-locale en && ng run credit:xliffmerge

Cannot find module '@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport-lib'                    
Error: Cannot find module '@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport-lib'
```

My package.json has the following dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport": "^1.1.5",
    "@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport-lib": "^1.12.0",
    "@ngx-i18nsupport/tooling": "^8.0.2",
    ...
}
```

I also tried installing the i18n libraries globally with no luck.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to do? Internationalization for angular is described in this article: https://angular.io/guide/i18n.

Comment: The i18n part is pretty straightforward but I was trying to set up the application to merge new elements into the existing xlf files.  This article talks about xliffmerge tool - https://medium.com/@ismaestro/angular-7-example-app-with-angularcli-angular-universal-i18n-official-firebase-66deac2dc31e

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  I stopped using the angular cli to run xliffmerge.  Instead I changed the extract-i118n target in my package.json to:

```
ng xi18n myapp --i18n-format xlf --output-path i18n --i18n-locale en 
&& xliffmerge --profile xliffmerge.json en fr
```

So instead of using the angular cli to run xliffmerge I am just running it directly.  I also added an xliffmerge json configuration file to my project.

Comment: What do you think is the reason? Using angular-cli v8.3.3 seems to be causing the issue whilst it worked fine for v7. Thanks for any update concerning the reason.

Answer (score 0):

what does xliffmerge.json contains?

Comment: I get the same error: 

> sps-spa@1.0.0 extract-i18n2 C:\DES\aytobcnimi\aytobcnimi.spsequipaspa
> ng xi18n frontend --i18n-format xlf --output-path translate --i18n-locale ca && xliffmerge --profile xliffmerge.json ca es

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@ngx-i18nsupport/ngx-i18nsupport-lib'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)